# I want to use libx264 codec with ffmpeg. but Ffmpeg libx264's configuration failed

Tags: ffmpeg

[configure failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1SyD.png)

I want to use libx264 codec with ffmpeg.
when i tried to convert image files to a video using the codec, a message appears said Unknown encoder "libx264". so I tried to execute configure and make again at msys folder. I typed ./configure --enable-libx264 and it failed. :(

my ffmpeg version is 3.0.1 and x264 is also the latest version so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that you don't have the x264 libraries for compiling on your machine.

The last time I compiled FFMpeg I downloaded and compiled x264 also along with it to ensure I had the libraries installed.

http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html

It may also interest you to enable OpenH264 by Cisco.

http://www.openh264.org/

Comment: thanks for your comment, Ruben Funai. actually I compiled FFMpeg again  but the configuration was still failed. but thanks anyway. what is the OpenH264? I couldn't understand when i went to the site cuz my english is not perfect. would you explain it briefly please?

Comment: Just to confirm, you downloaded the x264 source from the link I posted and did `./configure && make && make install` ?

OpenH264 is an encoder and decoder developed by Cisco. It basically does the same encoding as x264 without the pesky licensing issues that come along with x264. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenH264

You enable it in FFMpeg with `--enable-libopenh264` and then use it in FFMpeg with `-vcodec libopenh264`

Comment: Just a further note, if you plan to use OpenH264 then you need to also download the source and perform `make && make install`. The easiest way to download the source is to install `git` and then do `git clone https://github.com/cisco/openh264.git`

Comment: Hey, like you said, I installed x264 libraries&ffmpeg again in a new folder and compile x264 first then compile ffmpeg. then it works. thanks, mate! and also thank you for letting me know about H264.